# Как определять какой вебдрайвер нужен автоматически Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Что если я не могу заранее знать какой будет браузере на запускаемом компе. Как мне в коде определять вебдрайвер автоматически?

Comment: простой способ- проверять пути установки на наличие исполняемого файла. сложный способ- смотреть реестр для определения браузера по умолчанию (с линуксом хз как)

Comment: @ganz , драйвера уже должны быть поумолчания все установлены или их устанавливать лучше уже после определения браузера?

Comment: @Sergey_Derevianko я бы поставлял дрова вместе с программой на случай не возможности скачивания (удаление с сервра, строгие настройки файрвола, итд) , но чаще всего встречается вариант со скачиванием дополнительных компонентов. Так же стоит добавить проверку на то, что браузер не изменился те что пользователь не решил сменить браузер, ну и конечно материть юзера если он юзает амиги там всякие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например можно использовать **selene** или **selenide**, он сам определит установленный браузер, скачает и запустит нужный драйвер:

```
import selene.api
selene.api.browser.open_url('http://ya.ru')
```

> ```
> ====== WebDriver manager ======
> Current google-chrome version is 101.0.4951
> Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 google-chrome
> Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver_win32.zip
> Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\vadux\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\101.0.4951.41]
> ```

Или использовать только **webdriver_manager**, тут тоже определится установленный браузер, драйвер автоматически скачается и запустится:

```
import selenium.webdriver, selenium.common.exceptions, webdriver_manager.firefox, webdriver_manager.chrome, webdriver_manager.microsoft, webdriver_manager.utils, webdriver_manager.opera

def get_driver(i=0) -> selenium.webdriver.Chrome:
    try:  return Drivers[i]()
    except selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException as e:
        print('Текущий браузер не найден:', e)
        return get_driver(i + 1)
    except IndexError: raise selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException('браузер не найден')

Drivers = [
    lambda: selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=webdriver_manager.firefox.GeckoDriverManager().install()),
    lambda: selenium.webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=webdriver_manager.utils.ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()),
    lambda: selenium.webdriver.Ie(webdriver_manager.microsoft.IEDriverManager().install()),
    lambda: selenium.webdriver.Edge(webdriver_manager.microsoft.EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()),
    lambda: selenium.webdriver.Opera(executable_path=webdriver_manager.opera.OperaDriverManager().install()),
]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = get_driver()
    driver.get('http://ya.ru')
    print(driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Сделать стартовой'))
    driver.quit()
```

> ```
> ====== WebDriver manager ======
> Could not get version for firefox.Is firefox installed?
> Get LATEST geckodriver version for None firefox
> Getting latest mozilla release info for v0.31.0
> Trying to download new driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64.zip
> Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\vadux\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\win64\v0.31.0]
>
> ====== WebDriver manager ======
> Текущий браузер не найден: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
>
> Could not get version for chromium.Is chromium installed?
> Get LATEST chromedriver version for None chromium
> Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver_win32.zip
> Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\vadux\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\101.0.4951.41]
>
> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d1307776cda3e107646336462698064c", element="9191f724-259c-4ccb-a0ff-b2b7d89af652")>]
> ```